# how to push copyright down after position

Tags: html, css

Hello There i am trying to push the copy right down the content without the need to scroll down the content i made a comment in [this example here](https://jsfiddle.net/akkilah/85626d8a/) and its working but if i add height it will overflow each other when the content is extended any idea please

summary:i am trying to push the word "this is the page content" to be after the box

```
.tabs:after{
  /*content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  height:900px;*/
}
```

the example is in the line above for clear understanding

```css
.tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;

}

.tabs:after{
  /*content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  height:900px;*/
}

.tabs li{
  float: left;
}

ul.navbar li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:Black;
}

ul.navbar li:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tabs li > input{
  display: none;
}

.tabs li > label{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right-width:0;
  border-bottom-width:0;
}

.tabs li:last-child > label{
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.tabs .tab-content{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

/*functional*/
.tabs li > input:checked + label{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.tabs li > input:checked ~ .tab-content{
  display: block;

}
```

```html
  <ul class="tabs">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="" id="tab-1" checked>
        <label for="tab-1">First</label>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </h4>
             <p>adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offici
               a deserunt mollit anim id es  laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offici
              a deserunt mollit anim id es  laborum.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offici
                a deserunt mollit anim id es  laborum.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offici
                  a deserunt mollit anim id es  laborum.</p>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culp
                      a qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culp
                        a qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
            </div>

      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" value="" id="tab-2">
        <label for="tab-2">Secound</label>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <p>a deserunt mollit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidddatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offici
             anim id es  laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>this is the page content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace styles in jsfiddle

```
    .tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;

}

.tabs:after{
  /*content: "";
  display: block;
  clear:both;
  height:900px;*/
}
ul.navbar li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:Black;
}

ul.navbar li:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tabs li > input{
  display: none;
}

.tabs li > label{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right-width:0;
  border-bottom-width:0;
}

.tabs li:last-child > label{
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.tabs .tab-content{
  display: none;
  left:0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

/*functional*/
.tabs li > input:checked + label{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.tabs li > input:checked ~ .tab-content{
  display: block;
}
#tab-2 + label {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 116px;
}
#tab-1 + label {
  position: absolute;
    left:40px;
}
```

Comment: Yes , in your jsfiddle example. Hope it is what you want to achieve.

Comment: no not even near by  that i am trying to push the word "this is the page content" to be after the box